# Does the Thompson maneuver decrease sacroiliac pain?

Tags: medical-science

The Thompson maneuver is described here: http://www.miraclepainrelief.com/thompsonmaneuver.htm

The key claims are in this paragraph:

> The Thompson Maneuver simply brings the sacroiliac joints into their proper position.  Once the sacroiliac is back in normal position, the entire spine will eventually realign itself and pressure on sensitive tissues will diminish.

Is this true?